# Making a whole argument as string containing float values in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I am tying to pass a whole string to a method where the string contains the float values as well
e.g

```
 float ac_current ;
    char ac_current_char [MAX];
    
    ac_current = my_method()
    gcvt(ac_current , 6, ac_current_char );
  
    printf("current is: %s\n", ac_current_char );
```

This works fine , but I want a single string containing :

```
 "current is: %s\n", ac_current_char 


e.g current is 1.3422
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Use `sprintf`/`snprintf` to write the string into the buffer?

Comment: BTW, you should use `%e`, `%f` or `%g` for float values. `%s` is for strings...

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
gcvt - convert a floating-point number to a string

#include <stdlib.h>
char *gcvt(double number, int ndigit, char *buf);
```

and this function doesn't check the boundary of `buf` so I wouldn't use it. Check if there's a version that does bounds checking, or create your own:

```c
char *mygcvt(double number, int ndigit, char *buf, size_t size) {
    // return NULL if there's not enough room
    if(snprintf(buf, size, "%.*g", ndigit, number) >= size) return NULL;
    return buf;
}
```

Then use it to populate the `char[]` array:

```c
int main() {
    float ac_current;
    char ac_current_buf[MAX];
    
    ac_current = my_method();
    char* ac_current_char = mygcvt(ac_current, 6, ac_current_buf, MAX);
    
    if(ac_current_char == NULL) { // check that the conversion actually worked
        puts("the conversion requires a bigger buffer");

    } else {
        char ac_current_str[TOTALMAX];

        if(TOTALMAX <= snprintf(ac_current_str, TOTALMAX,
                                "current is: %s\n", ac_current_char))
        {
            puts("the whole string wouldn't fit");
        } else
        {   // success
            puts(ac_current_str);
        }        
    }
}
```

---

The floating point conversion and putting it into a string could however be simplified by combining the two by skipping the `gcvt` step:

```c
int main() {
    float ac_current;

    char ac_current_char[MAX];
    ac_current = my_method();
        
    if(snprintf(ac_current_char, MAX, "current is: %.*g\n", 6, ac_current) >= MAX)
    {
        puts("the whole string wouldn't fit");
    } else
    {   // success        
        puts(ac_current_char);
    }        
}
```

Comment: You can just validate with `if (snprintf(buf, size, "%.*g", ndigit, number) > size - 1) { /* handle error */ }`. There isn't a need for the `reglen` check first (doesn't hurt, just an extra check)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Of course, I even used the same strategy in my second example :-) Thanks!

Comment: I'm am getting blind or deliriously tired. Youngest daughter's 17th b-day tonight and she got a 3D printer (which assembly started around midnight....) Yep either way is fine (and I actually think it is a great idea to introduce the `snprintf (NULL, 0, ...)` approach (trick) as well).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :-) Sounds like fun! Yeah, `snprintf(NULL, 0, ...` can be useful, but now that you pointed out the simplification, I can't find room for it in the answer :)